# How can I develope vf page related child object EmailMessage to case object?

Tags: related-list

Can any one tell me how can I get related list from case object.I need to display EmailMessage(child object).Here sample code but not get anything.What did I wrong please help me out?

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:relatedList list="EmailMessage" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

The relationship name is `EmailMessages`. I think it is not possible to access this relationship through the visualforce page using relatedList tag. All my attempts are failed with the following error:

> 'EmailMessages' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Case

BUT you can access it using the merge variable syntax like following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Case.EmailMessages}" var="email">
            <apex:column value="{!email.ToAddress}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!email.Status}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!email.MessageDate}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!email.TextBody}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

This works pretty well and can be a good workaround.